# extract a subset of deep embed json and print only key,value pair I am interested in the subset json

Tags: json, jq

I have a deep embeded json file:
I want to extract and parse only the subset I am interested in , in my case all content in 'node' key.
How can I:

1. extract subset of this json file which contains `"edges[].node"` (edges is the 'parent' key of node)
2. in `'node'` session , I am interested in key:value pair of

   ```
   .url,
   .headline.default, (*this one is 'grandchild' of key 'node'*)
   .firstPublished
   ```

   I want to keep **only above 3 item inside 'node' key**
   How can I print out the super slim version of json file I need ?
3. a better to have option is : can I still keep the **structure/full path** which leads json root key to embed 'node' json subset I am interested in ?

> Here is the [jqplay-myjson](https://jqplay.org/s/gSpv_jEDbh) (**full content of my json file**)

Try to attach my full content here :

```
{
  "data": {
    "legacyCollection": {
      "longDescription": "The latest news, analysis and investigations from Europe.",
      "section": {
        "name": "world",
        "url": "/section/world"
      },
      "collectionsPage": {
        "stream": {
          "pageInfo": {
            "hasNextPage": true,
            "__typename": "PageInfo"
          },
          "__typename": "AssetsConnection",
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/video/world/europe/100000008323381/icc-war-crimes-ukraine.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T23:28:33.241Z",
                "headline": {
                  "default": "I.C.C. Joins Investigation of War Crimes in Ukraine",
                  "__typename": "CreativeWorkHeadline"
                },
                "summary": "Karim Khan, the chief prosecutor of the International Criminal Court, said that his organization would participate in a joint effort — with Ukraine, Poland and Lithuania — to investigate war crimes committed since Russia’s invasion.",
                "promotionalMedia": {
                  "__typename": "Image",
                  "id": "SW1hZ2U6bnl0Oi8vaW1hZ2UvYTY3MTVhNDUtZDE0NS01OWZjLThkZWItNzYxMWViN2UyODhk"
                },
                "embedded": false
              },
              "__typename": "AssetsEdge"
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "__typename": "Article",
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/27/sports/soccer/chelsea-sale-roman-abramovich.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T19:42:17.000Z",
                "typeOfMaterials": [
                  "News"
                ],
                "archiveProperties": {
                  "lede": "",
                  "__typename": "ArticleArchiveProperties"
                },
                "headline": {
                  "default": "Endgame Nears in Bidding for Chelsea F.C.",
                  "__typename": "CreativeWorkHeadline"
                },
                "summary": "The American bank selling the English soccer team on behalf of its Russian owner could name its preferred suitor by the end of the week. But the drama isn’t over.",
                "translations": []
              },
              "__typename": "AssetsEdge"
            }
          ],
          "totalCount": 52559
        }
      },
      "sourceId": "100000004047788",
      "tagline": "",
      "__typename": "LegacyCollection"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the command I have [jqplay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/m4mofOjUU_):

```
.data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges[].node|= with_entries(select([.key]|inside(["default","url","firstPublished"]))
```

And here is the output I got

```
{
  "data": {
    "legacyCollection": {
      "longDescription": "The latest news, analysis and investigations from Europe.",
      "section": {
        "name": "world",
        "url": "/section/world"
      },
      "collectionsPage": {
        "stream": {
          "pageInfo": {
            "hasNextPage": true,
            "__typename": "PageInfo"
          },
          "__typename": "AssetsConnection",
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/video/world/europe/100000008323381/icc-war-crimes-ukraine.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T23:28:33.241Z"
              },
              "__typename": "AssetsEdge"
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/27/sports/soccer/chelsea-sale-roman-abramovich.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T19:42:17.000Z"
              },
              "__typename": "AssetsEdge"
            }
          ],
          "totalCount": 52559
        }
      },
      "sourceId": "100000004047788",
      "tagline": "",
      "__typename": "LegacyCollection"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output I **expect to have**

```
{
  "data": {
    "legacyCollection": {
      "collectionsPage": {
        "stream": {
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/video/world/europe/100000008323381/icc-war-crimes-ukraine.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T23:28:33.241Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/27/sports/soccer/chelsea-sale-roman-abramovich.html",
                "firstPublished": "2022-04-27T19:42:17.000Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  In particular, a concise example should be provided directly (not a link to an external site) with corresponding expected output, or a set of output variants if you are flexible in that regard.

Comment: @peak updated my posts and added more info

Comment: Good, but .headline.default is not shown in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (somewhat) declarative solution:

```
(.data.legacyCollection.collectionsPage.stream.edges
 | map( {node: (.node
                | {url,
                   firstPublished,
                   headline: {default: .headline.default} })})) as $edges
| {data: {
     legacyCollection: {
       collectionsPage: {
         stream: {
           $edges
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to make the selection while ensuring that the structure is preserved. This solution may be of interest because
it can easily be adapted for use with jq's "--stream" option.

```
def array_startswith($head): .[: $head|length] == $head;

. as $in
| ["data", "legacyCollection", "collectionsPage", "stream", "edges"] as $head
| ($head|length) as $len
| reduce (paths
          | select( array_startswith($head) and .[1+$len] == "node" )) as $p
    (null;
     if ((($p|length) == $len + 3) and ($p[-1] | IN("url", "firstPublished")))
        or ((($p|length) == $len + 4) and $p[-2:] == ["headline", "default"])
     then setpath($p; $in | getpath($p))
     else .
     end)
```